# Calling a setup.cmd and waiting for it complete

Tags: batch-file, wait

I am running 1 st batch utility calling another 2nd batch.  The 2nd batch calls a setup.cmd command which has internal Java code to patch files.

When I just call the 2nd batch from 1st batch --

1. 1st batch calls the second batch
2. 2nd batch calls the setup.cmd
3. 1st batch continues with further code without waiting for setup.cmd to complete.

I tried using start /wait to call the setup.cmd but that does not returns back the control to 1st batch.  It keeps the session after installing.

1st batch calls 2nd batch by using CALL
2nd batch has following code to call setup.cmd

```
%windir%\system32\cmd /c start /WAIT Disk1\setup.cmd %parameter%
```

How can I get the control back to 1st batch once the setup.cmd completes?

Comment: I think in fact, the first calls the second and waits, the second calls setup.cmd and waits. Setup.cmd starts the Java program and ends as soon as it is started. So setup.cmd returns almost immediately, after which both 2 and 1 respectively end as well. So (if I'm right) the issue is, how to make setup.cmd wait for the java program. I don't think `/wait` is valid.

Comment: I agree with GolezTrol.  Try executing setup.cmd /?  to see if it gives you any help.  Perhaps there is a parameter switch that you can use to make setup.cmd wait.

Comment: Thanks for responding guys...I can see from the task manager that the java code is still running and doing the patches...but even after the installation is complete...I can see the 1st and second batch file still running...what I want is as soon as setup.cmd task is complete...it shd continue with rest of the commands in 1st batch....that's why i am also using cmd /c

Comment: And without /wait it wont wait for 2nd batch complete and move with 1st batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this last week by using loops and by calling the setup.cmd...sorry for delay in this post.

```
@echo off
CALL \Installers\Disk1\setup.cmd -i silent -FILE=\Silent\Silent.txt

:LOOP

tasklist /FI "username eq SOMEUSER" 2>NUL | find /I /N "java">NUL
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%

if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (
  GOTO CONTINUE
) ELSE (
  ECHO PATCH is still running, Sleeping for 5 Mins
  SLEEP 300
  GOTO LOOP
)

:CONTINUE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just use this without the start command, and `call batch2` then it will wait until it is finished.

```
call Disk1\setup.cmd %parameter%
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but after calling BATCH2....it returns the control immediately to batch1. It does wait for setup.cmd to complete in batch2. In my next command in batch1 I validate the successful installation if setup.cmd...which obviously fails as setup.cmd is still running...

Comment: OHH!  I just realised it is a batch file too.  Just add the `call` keyword that you see in my edited answer above.

Comment: Not Working....it calls the setup.cmd -- the java code runs in background...and batch continues to next command.

Comment: I can see the Java Code working and doing its job successfully.  Just that my batch doesn't waits for it to complete and directly goes to next codeline.

Comment: Yes, it is the way it is being launched in `setup.cmd` so show us the commands and we'll suggest something.